# How to access child class in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am trying to scrape the following page: https://www.inmuebles24.com/departamentos-en-renta-en-orizaba.html. I want to access the children of postings-container and the information within them.

I have tried response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'postings-container')]") and other commands but they always come back empty.
I'm starting to learn scrapy so any correct command, advice or links that would guide me would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression is prettty much correct but the main issue here is that the website is protected by `Cloudflare protection` thats why no tool and technique is working here. See the below image:

[image]

So, I tried scrapy with CloudScraper but didn't work.

```
#Not working
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import cloudscraper

class inmuebles24(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "inmu"
    allowed_domains = ["inmuebles24.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.inmuebles24.com/departamentos-en-venta.html"]
    

    def start_requests(self):
        scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse, meta={'scraper': scraper})

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('body')
        print(products)
       

process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(inmuebles24)


process.start()
```

**However, Only Cloudscraper works:**

```
import cloudscraper
from parsel import Selector
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = 'https://www.inmuebles24.com/departamentos-en-venta.html'
req = scraper.get(url)
selector = Selector(text=req.text, type='xml')
for p in selector.xpath('//div[@class="sc-12dh9kl-3 iqNJlX"]/text()'):
  price = p.get()
  print(price.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
MN 2,457,598
MN 4,500,000
MN 550,000
MN 1,879,000
MN 3,034,000
MN 2,800,000
MN 10,000,000
MN 6,000,000
MN 2,300,000
MN 36,000,000
MN 16,900,000
MN 25,000,000
MN 4,700,000
MN 7,450,000
MN 5,500,000
MN 2,425,831
MN 2,885,325
MN 7,850,000
MN 11,000,000
MN 5,250,000
```

**N.B:**
Select the desired url correctly to scrape data. Go to department and choose a department from dropdown list to get correctly data organized url.